# Prove that $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}{(e^{b_n}-1)}$ converges, given that $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}{b_n}$ converges absolutely.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, absolute-convergence

It's a question from a test that I had, and I don't know how to prove this, so I am forwarding this to you.

$\sum \limits_{n=0}^{\infty }\:b_n$ is absolutely convergent series . How to prove that the series $\sum \limits_{n=0}^{\infty }\:(e^{b_n}\:-\:1)$ is also absolutely convergent?

We **cannot** assume here that $b_n\:\ge 0$ for every $n$.

Comment: Skimming some of the answers, I decided to post one with a somewhat different style of thinking, less.... "technical" perhaps.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As $b_n\rightarrow 0$. There is some $N$ such that for every $n>N$, $|b_n|<1$. 
$$b_n\le e^{b_n}-1 =b_n+\frac{b^2_n}{2!}+\frac{b_n^3}{3!}+\cdots \le b_n+|b_n|\left(1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2^2}+\cdots\right)\le b_n+2{|b_n|}$$ and hence
$$|e^{b_n}-1|<\max\left\{|b_n|,|b_n+|2{b_n}|| \right\}<4|b_n|$$
Now use [comparison test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_comparison_test).

Comment: How do you know that $b_n≤e^b_n−1$ ?

Comment: @user2637293 It follows from $e^x>1+x$ for all $x$.

Comment: and how do you prove that ex>1+x? sorry for to many question it seems the easiest solution but i realy want to know the whole steps

Comment: @user2637293: That depends on how you define $e^x$, if you define it by $e^x=1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}+\cdots$, then for $x>0$, the inequality is trivial, otherwise use that $\frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!}+\frac{x^(2n+1)}{(2n+1)!}>0$.

Answer (score 2):

A neat argument:

if $x\in [0,1]$, then by mean value theorem, $\displaystyle \left|\frac{e^x -e^0}{x} \right| \leq e^1$

That is to say, $|x|\leq 1 \implies |e^x-1|\leq e^1|x|$

---

Since $b_n\to 0$, there is some $N$ such that $n\geq N \implies |b_n|\leq 1$

Then, for fixed $M$, $\displaystyle \sum_{n=N}^M |e^{b_n}-1|\leq e^1\sum_{n=N}^M  |b_n|$

Hence $\displaystyle \sum_{n\geq N} e^{b_n}-1$ is absolutely convergent and $\displaystyle \sum_{n\geq 1} e^{b_n}-1$ also is.

Answer (score 2):

The limit comparison test tell us that if $\sum |b_n|$ converges and $\lim |a_n|/|b_n| = L \neq 0$ then $\sum |a_n|$ converges.

Notice that since $\sum b_n$ converges then $b_n \to 0$. Now consider $$\frac{e^{b_n} - 1}{b_n}.$$

Since $b_n$ is going to zero, this means that the limit is the same as the derivative of $e^x$ at $x=0$. In other words: $$\frac{e^{b_n} - 1}{b_n} \to 1$$ and the series $\sum (e^{b_n} - 1)$ converges.

Answer (score 1):

Another one, using the equivalent test (aka the limit comparison test): since $\sum_n b_n$ is convergent, then $b_n\underset{n\to+\infty}\longrightarrow0$, hence
$$\mathrm{e}^{b_n}-1\underset{n\to+\infty}\sim b_n,$$
hence
$$\bigl\lvert\mathrm{e}^{b_n}-1\bigr\rvert\underset{n\to+\infty}\sim\lvert b_n\rvert\geq0,$$
hence by the equivalent test, the series $\sum_n\mathrm{e}^{b_n}-1$ converges absolutely.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\text{If $b$ is any real number then }e^b-1\ge b\tag 1
$$
and
$$
\text{if $0<b\ll1$ then }e^b-1<2b. \tag 2
$$

From $(1)$ we get $0\le e^b-1\le b\le 2b$ if $1\gg b\ge0$ and from $(2)$ we get $|e^b-1|<|b|$ if $b<0$.  Either way we have
$$
|e^b-1|\le 2|b|\text{ if $b$ is close enough to $0$.} \tag 3
$$
And $b_n$ will be close enough to $0$ for all but finitely many $n$ because $b_n\to0$ as $n\to\infty$.

Thus $(3)$ tells us that $\sum_n (e^{b_n}-1)$ converges by a comparison test.

So how do we know that $(1)$ and $(2)$ are true?

The exponential function is concave upward since is second derivative is everywhere positive.  Therefore it lies above all of its tangent lines.  The line $b\mapsto b+1$ is tangent to $b\mapsto e^b$ at $b=0$, so lying above its tangent line means $e^b\ge b+1$.  That gives us $(1)$.

Next notice that the line $b\mapsto 1+2b$ passes through the point $(0,1)$, and so does the curve $b\mapsto e^b$, but the line has a greater slope than the curve at that point.  Therefore, immediately to the right of that point (i.e. $0<b\ll 1$) the line $b\mapsto 1+2b$ lies above the curve $b\mapsto e^b$.  That gives us $(2)$.

(The mean value theorem is tacitly used here, since it is at the heart of the proofs of some basic facts about the relationship between derivatives and graphs.)

Answer (score 0):

Hint: for sufficiently small $|x|$  and sufficiently large $C>0$ you have $$|e^x-1|\le |x|+C|x|^2.$$