# Prove that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty b^{a_n}-1$ is convergent

Tags: sequences-and-series

**Question**

Let $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_n<\infty$

$a_n>0$ foreach n. Let $b>1$

Prove that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty b^{a_n}-1$  is convergent

Thanks

**My Attempt**
I tried to use the Convergence tests but I don't know how exactly

Comment: This is no site for solving your homework. If you expect a solution, you need to provide some of your work, i.e. what you have tried.

Comment: I can't see a question.

Comment: Closely related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/854093/prove-that-sum-limits-n-0-inftyeb-n-1-converges-given-that-sum

Answer (score 0):

**hint**: since $a_n$ goes to $0$ and your series is a series of positive terms (why ?), you may consider to rewrite the general term as $e^{a_n\ln(b)} - 1$. Now use asymptotic expansion...